# Does Split Hex stack with the Rod of Voracious Hexes?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, witch

First, we have the feat *Split Hex*, described below:

> *You can split the effect of one of your targeted hexes, affecting another creature you can see.*
>
> Prerequisites: Witch level 10th.
>
> Benefit: When you use one of your hexes (not a major hex or a grand hex) that targets a single creature, you can choose another creature within 30 feet of the first target to also be targeted by the hex.

Then, we have the Rod of Voracious Hexes, the stats for which are listed below:

> Price 32,500 gp; Slot none; CL 17th; Weight 5 lbs.; Aura strong (no school)
>
> Three times per day when a wielder of this rod uses a hex (but not an advanced hex or grand hex), she can use this rod's power to target not only the hex's normal target, but also another target within 30 feet of the first. The hex must normally target a single creature within a range of at least 30 feet.
>
> CONSTRUCTION REQUIREMENTS: Cost 16,250 gp; *Craft Rod*; *Split Hex*, creator must have the hex class feature

One of my players is playing a Witch who has taken the Split Hex feat, and they are wondering if they can craft a Rod of Voracious Hexes and use it to target a third creature. Is this legal?

I am inclined to say this wouldn't be legal, for two reasons:

- The construction requirements for the rod seem to indicate that this rod is supposed to simulate the split hex feat, and Pathfinder generally doesn't allow you to make the same effect stack.
- If the player uses a split hex, that hex now targets two creatures. The last clause of the rules for the rod--"the hex must normally target a single creature within a range of at least 30 feet"--seems to disallow that. I am construing "normally" to mean "before the applying the bonuses from the rod".

But, on the other hand, I could see counterarguments to both of the above points:

- The Pathfinder stacking rules apply to numeric bonuses; split hex is not a numeric bonus.
- The last clause says "the hex must *normally* target a single creature." The word "normally" here could be construed as meaning "before the application of any other hex-related feats."

Answer (score 3):

I believe that a witch could use a Rod of Voracious Hexes along with Split Hex to target 3 creatures at one time.

The rod doesn't specify that the hex must target a single creature, just that the additional target and the normal target be within 30 feet. So, a witch targets creature A with a hex, uses Split Hex to also target creature B and the rod to target creature C; as long as B and C are both within 30 feet of A, all three should be affected. There is an argument to be made that all three may need to be within 30 feet of each other for the rod to work, if one assumes that Split Hex makes both A and B the "normal target", but I feel it's a weak one.

As a GM, I'd have no problem with this ruling, not least because the witch is paying 32k for the rod which only works 3x/day. It's extremely easy to blow through three uses in a single combat (one of the first things I found Googling around for this combination was to use the rod to hit three targets with Evil Eye then Slumber - which is a potent combination, but can only happen once per day).

Comment: In reality, I might end up allowing it based on the balance argument. But the rod does specify explicitly that "The hex must normally target a single creature within a range of at least 30 feet," so I'm not sure your answer would function as a RAW explanation.

Comment: @mlefavor  However, the game is remarkably cavalier about using but not explaining *normally*. Here, *normally* could simply apply to the original, unmodified hex.

Comment: I agree that it could, but it also could just as well mean something else—are there any examples of similar situations in the rules that would support that interpretation?

Answer (score -1):

The RAW interpretation is that Split Hex is not a numeric bonus, and the rod's capacity and the feat one are not the same, but as the hex have to target only one creature for each of them to apply they actually **can't stack**.

The word "normally" here refers to the fact that the rod by itself makes the use condition false, so you have to ignore the rod's effect to determine if the hex targets one creature or not. It doesn't allow you to ignore other modifications.

That said, this RAW application seems very not fun to me. Combining the two effects is good but not game-breaking as it's pretty expensive too.